# Error: Entrypoint is not a Dart file in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, program-entry-point, entry-point

I have a this  Error: Entrypoint is not a Dart file in android studio.

### Click on File-> Project Structure -> Module then add root folder of your project.
I have done this things but it not resolved and My all file icons showing like text file.
How to resolve this, Please help me! Thank you!

[image]

### Answer: By mistake my all project dart file changed into text.
after some time I have changed text to dart then it worked.

Comment: Have you enabled dart support for project?

Answer (score 0):

click file->setting->Editor->file types ( delete expention .dart in file text)